# Why does the compiler say "undeclared identifier" when I try to show form B from form A?

Tags: delphi, pascal

Why this code is not working:

```
procedure TFormNotification.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FormB.Show;
end;
```

I'm getting *Undeclared identifier* error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably have a global variable named `FormB` declared in the `interface` section of a unit named `UnitB`. But `UnitA` doesn't know anything about that unit or its contents. In particular, it doesn't know what the word `FormB` means — that identifier is undeclared.

To tell `UnitA` about the things declared in `UnitB`, add `UnitB` to the *uses clause* in `UnitA`:

```
uses Windows, SysUtils, Forms, Classes, UnitB;
```

Comment: And, there is no need to use in interface section

Comment: What if i can fully compile the project, yet i get numerous 'Undeclared identifier' message on 'Structure' panel (delphi 2010).

Comment: @Kidbro, to my knowledge, the structure view has been broken forever. https://stackoverflow.com/q/21483883/33732

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the unit in which FormB is declared to your uses clause.